# Producer for dynamic instance not getting annotation

Tags: java, jboss, cdi

I am having a producer class that looks like this:

```
public class HostConfigPropertyProducer {
    @Any
    @Inject
    Instance<String> baseUriInstance;

    @Produces
    @HostConfigProperty
    String produce(InjectionPoint ip) {
        HostConfigProperty property =  ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(HostConfigProperty.class);
        Instance<String> baseUriCandidate = baseUriInstance.select(new StringPropertyLiteral(property.key()));
        return baseUriCandidate.get();
    }
}
```

The StringPropertyLiteral is looking like this:

```
public final class StringPropertyLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<StringProperty> implements StringProperty {
    private final String keyValue;

    public StringPropertyLiteral(String key) {
        keyValue = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return keyValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String defaultValue() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now there is also a `@Produces` for `StringProperty` that I am trying to invoke using my `select(new StringP...)`. It correctly goes into that producer but the problem is that it is not able to get a `StringProperty` annotation in that code.

More specifically that means that in the following code it gets null:

```
@Produces
@StringProperty
public String stringProperty(InjectionPoint ip) {
    StringProperty property = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(StringProperty.class);
    return property.defaultValue();
}
```

The `getAnnotation` is returning `null` and inspecting it in the debugger shows that it only has 2 annotations, the `Any` and the `Inject` annotation. Also in the qualifiers of the injection point I can find only one qualifier, thats `Any`

Why is my annotation literal not being passed to the producer? I have used a similar pattern in another context but there the target for `select` was a type, that was not obtained by a producer and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion here is how the `InjectionPoint` works. When you make a dynamic select (`Instance#select()`), it will not create a new injection point. It will still refer to the original injection point you had. 
E.g. in your second producer you do this:

```
public String stringProperty(InjectionPoint ip) {
   StringProperty property = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(StringProperty.class);
```

However, the injection point you get here will be the *original one*:

```
@Any
@Inject
Instance<String> baseUriInstance;
```

And as such, this IP does not have the annotation you request (`StringProperty`), hence the `null` value.

This simply won't work and you will need to work around it. I would probably need to see more of your code to help you with it. It seems as a kind of unusual design to chain producer calls like this.

Comment: Ah, thats sad, so the producer cannot access any additional qualifiers? The idea is that the `StringPropertyProducer` does a database lookup to fetch configuration. For certain properties an additional step must be done  which `HostConfigPropertyProducer` would do. I didnt want to repeat all the logic `StringPropertyProducer` is doing (also because this comes from a library)

Comment: Normally, the producer can access additional qualifiers (via `InjectionPoint`) but *not in your specific case*, because there, the injection point is just an `@Any Instance<String>` and that's what you will see. What you could do is store the information you need (the value of `HostConfigProperty` annotation I guess?) in an external construct - say, a bean that you later destroy - which the other producer would then read and based on that react. Does that make sense?